# com.databricks.spark.xml.util.XSDToSchema,import java.nio.file.Paths

Tags: xml-parsing, spark-streaming, databricks, azure-databricks

For the above I am unable to import it in databricks,
From maven repo, groupId: com.databricks
,artifactId: spark-xml_2.12,version: 0.14.0 were installed, however still I'm getting [XML error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6Q1A.png)
[Java import error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXbVH.png) - pip install I did already,

can someone advise how to fix it.

have nested schema, I have to use xsd file to read schema,

Iam unable to import XSDschema to run
schema = XSDToSchema.read(Paths.get("/path/to/your.xsd"))

Comment: Welcome to SO! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. See: "[How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". Also, please read "[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/128421)".

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below Workaround

```
val df = spark.read
      .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
      .option("rowTag", "file_name")
      .xml("folder_path/file_name.xml")
```

Alternatively, you can also use the short form `format("xml")` and `load("src/main/resources/persons.xml")`

While API reads XML file into DataFrame, It automatically infers the schema based on data. Below schema outputs from `df.printSchma()` .

For more information follow this [article](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-read-write-xml/) by NNK.

Refer - https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml

Comment: have nested schema, I have to use xsd file to read schema,

import com.databricks.spark.xml.util.XSDToSchema
import java.nio.file.Paths

 Iam unable to import XSDschema to run
schema = XSDToSchema.read(Paths.get("/path/to/your.xsd"))